Docker containers fail all SSL operations
I have docker-ce installed on a Debian machine. I'm stuck with some strange behavior where the containers are unable to fetch anything nor make some requests.
root@machine:~# docker run --rm -it alpine sh
/ # nslookup google.com
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.212.206

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:4009:80a::200e

/ # ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=114 time=1.346 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=1 ttl=114 time=1.465 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=2 ttl=114 time=1.332 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=3 ttl=114 time=1.396 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=4 ttl=114 time=1.623 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=5 ttl=114 time=1.380 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=6 ttl=114 time=1.392 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=7 ttl=114 time=1.484 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=8 ttl=114 time=1.323 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=9 ttl=114 time=1.339 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=10 ttl=114 time=1.354 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=11 ttl=114 time=1.394 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=12 ttl=114 time=1.333 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
13 packets transmitted, 13 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 1.323/1.397/1.623 ms
/ # apk add --no-cache -v curl
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz

The apk command just hangs there.
It looks like a SSL problem to me, as a failing container (Google's gcr.io/cloud-tagging-10302018/gtm-cloud-image:stable) throws error 112 (unrecognized name):
gtm-tc  | Node.js v18.19.1
gtm-tc  | Fetching server bootstrap JS from https://www.googletagmanager.com/static/serverjs/server_bootstrap.js failed.
gtm-tc  | node:internal/process/promises:288
gtm-tc  |             triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
gtm-tc  |             ^
gtm-tc  | 
gtm-tc  | Error: write EPROTO 00E8548A407F0000:error:0A000458:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 unrecognized name:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1590:SSL alert number 112
gtm-tc  | 
gtm-tc  |     at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (node:internal/stream_base_commons:94:16) {
gtm-tc  |   errno: -71,
gtm-tc  |   code: 'EPROTO',
gtm-tc  |   syscall: 'write'
gtm-tc  | }

I've also tried building a container from alpine and the apk add command failed with unauthorized response.
I do have a nginx server running in a container which is able to handle SSL though.
I really don't know where to look. I've tried to completely remove docker-ce and reinstall it, I've checked iptables if something was strange but didn't find anything abnormal. There is no other firewall installed on this machine.
Do someone have an idea?
Edit:
This openssl command on my faulty machine might give some clues on what is wrong (the response is great on other machines):
root@machine:~# openssl s_client -connect mydomain.com:443
140684422116672:error:0200206F:system library:connect:Connection refused:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
140684422116672:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
140684422116672:error:0200206F:system library:connect:Connection refused:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
140684422116672:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
connect:errno=111


Connect to the docker using  docker run --rm -it alpine sh  and then update the SSL libraries:
apk update  and then apk upgrade
Have you tried to do the same thing by using another image (like ubutu) as mentioned in the answer?

That looks like that while basic networking (like DNS resolution and ICMP) is working fine within your Docker containers, there's an issue specifically related to SSL/TLS connections.
First, make sure the host can establish SSL connections:
curl -v https://www.google.com

If the host fails here, the problem is not Docker-specific but rather with the host's networking or SSL configuration.
Now check if the necessary ports are exposed and mapped correctly between the host and the Docker containers. If you're running services that require specific ports, ensure these ports are exposed in the Dockerfile and mapped correctly in the docker run command.
# In Dockerfile
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

When running the container, map the ports to the host:
docker run -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --name mycontainer myimage

If your application uses SSL certificates, make sure these certificates are correctly configured and accessible within the container. For instance, if you're using NGINX, ensure the certificate files are correctly mapped and NGINX is configured to use them.
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/mycert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/mykey.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://mybackend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

Docker run command with volume mapping:
docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 \
    -v /path/to/certs:/etc/ssl/certs \
    -v /path/to/keys:/etc/ssl/private \
    --name mynginx nginx

Also, make sure the SSL certificates are valid and have the correct permissions. Certificates should be readable by the processes that need them:
sudo openssl x509 -in /path/to/mycert.crt -text -noout

Check permissions:
ls -la /path/to/mycert.crt /path/to/mykey.key

Outdated SSL libraries can cause issues. Make sure your Docker image has the latest versions of OpenSSL and other related libraries, Alpine example:
docker run --rm -it alpine sh
apk update
apk upgrade

Make sure Docker is correctly configured to use your host's DNS settings. Sometimes, Docker containers might not correctly inherit DNS settings from the host.
cat /etc/docker/daemon.json

If the file is missing or doesn't contain DNS settings, you might want to add them:
{
    "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]
}

Restart the Docker service:
sudo systemctl restart docker

Since openssl s_client -connect mydomain.com:443 gives a connection refused error, it indicates there might be an issue with outbound SSL connections on the host itself. This could be due to several reasons including firewall rules, missing or misconfigured SSL libraries.
Verify that there are no outbound connection restrictions (e.g., iptables rules):
sudo iptables -L -v -n

Look for any rules that might be blocking outbound SSL connections!
Given the SSL errors, there might be a problem with the SSL libraries on your host. Reinstall OpenSSL and other related libraries.
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall openssl ca-certificates

Since you're using Alpine, there might be an issue specific to that image. Try using a different base image like Debian or Ubuntu to see if the problem persists.
docker run --rm -it debian bash
apt-get update
apt-get install -y curl
curl -v https://www.google.com

Sometimes IPv6 can cause issues if not configured correctly. You can disable IPv6 in Docker by adding the following to the Docker daemon.json file:
{
    "ipv6": false
}

And then restart the Docker service:
sudo systemctl restart docker

Examine the system logs for any errors or warnings that could provide more context.
sudo journalctl -u docker
sudo dmesg | grep docker

Inspect the Docker network settings to make sure there are no misconfigurations:
docker network ls
docker network inspect bridge

Now you should be able to identify and resolve the issue affecting SSL/TLS connections in your Docker containers.
